# How to change an image and text to text on mouseover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create an effect in a content box where an icon is displayed along with a short line of text underneath. On mouseover I want it to change to just some text, but I like both the border and the text to change color. So far I have managed to create the text and change the color, but am having troubles with properly displaying the image as well as changing the text. A good example of what I would like it to look like in the end is found on https://www.upwork.com/ in the grid section just below the header "Work with someone perfect for your team". However, they have style sheets with references all over the place so I'm looking for something that is simpler in the setup. It will be used to create an effect on a small set of elements on a Wordpress site.

The HTML I have so far is:

```html
<p>
<a class="box-transition box-size box-color box-padding box-border salesimage" href="http://www.accelerantbsp.com/services/sales-support-administrative-services/">Sales, Support & Administrative Services
</a></p>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.box-transition{
    transition:All .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:All .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:All .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:All .4s ease-in-out;
}
.box-color {
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    text-decoration: none;
}
.box-padding{
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
.box-border{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.box-color:hover{
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    color: blue;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.box-padding:hover{
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
.box-border:hover{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.salesimage {
  background-image: url([1]);
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: relative;
  background-size: medium;
  -webkit-background-size: medium;
  -moz-background-size: medium;
  -o-background-size: medium; 
}
.salesimage:hover {
  display: hidden;
}
```

Trying to stay within HTML5 and CSS3 as I am early on in my learning curve and not too familiar with JavaScript yet - although I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to use the a:hover tag? You should not have so many class in a tag. 
Learn more at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

The effects you want to achieve are:

- text
- border

To change the text, you can simply show hide on hover. Add another span with additional text and show it on hover. But showing the text with displayed block or nine won't create any transition effect. To create transition effects, you would have to combine opacity and height.

When it has to be hidden, span's height and opacity will be 0; and when it needs to be shown, its height and opacity will be auto and 1 respectively.

To change the border color, you can have some border color in beginning and set new border color on hover.

And as there are effects transitioning css is already there in `box-transition` section, they will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

you use so many classes. no need of so many classes.

take

```
<div class="one">-----
       <div class="two">-----</div>
 </div>
```

1.class one is before mouse over the first div.

2. when class one is visible write the style of class two is

   `two{
     display:none;
      }`
3. After mouse over on class 'one' write css like

   `.one:hover .two{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
   }`

if u want any inside  anchors,paragraphs,headings use by your own styling.

here is example  [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ramachandra/MBLZx/1732/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should work for you.

1) Create a `wrapper` div that will hold this box.
2) create 2 divs each one holds the content that should show before and after mouse hover.
3) Make both these child divs `position:absolute`
4) Set `z-index` to the first child so that it overlaps on the second child. So you can now see only one div
5) On `hover` of this first child remove its `z-index` so the second one can overlap on the first one.

Sample demo below, Change the content and colors as per your requirements (you can add icons, images, text etc)

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.first,
.second {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
.second {
  background-color: green;
}
.first {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: blue;
}
.first:hover {
  z-index: 0;
}
.second:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div class="first">First random stuff goes here</div>
  <div class="second">Second stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```